# Como redirecionar o utilizador para a página que estava tentando aceder antes de ser pedido o login?

Tags: php, html

Imaginem o seguinte cenário:

Tenho um site com um formulário de inscrição para pessoas que queiram candidatar-se a um determinado cargo.

O que acontece atualmente é que quando a pessoa submete a inscrição, recebe um e-mail automático a indicar que a mesma foi submetida para aprovação e é enviado, também, um outro e-mail automático para a pessoa responsável em gerir estas as inscrições. Neste último e-mail é apresentado um link de acesso ao backoffice, que está por detrás disto tudo, em que é possível aprovar ou rejeitar essa inscrição, despoletando um conjunto de ações.

Acontece que essa página é privada (apenas para os membros da organização) sendo que, caso a sessão não esteja criada, é feito um redirect para a página de login.

A minha dúvida consiste em saber como é que, depois de efetuado o login, consigo redirecionar a pessoa para o link que estava a tentar aceder anteriormente (o de aprovação/rejeição daquela inscrição específica).

Se possível, dêem-me um exemplo prático, por favor.

Muito obrigado.

Comment: Sempre que redirecionar para a tela de login, você passa a página atual como parâmetro,e ao efetuar login você verifica se esse parâmetro está preenchido, se estiver você redireciona para a página que está salva nele.

Comment: Antes de redirecionar o usuário para o login, cria uma sessão com a URL que o usuário tentou acessar. Após ele logar, verifica se existe essa sessão de redirecionamento criada. Se sim, redireciona o usuário para aquela URL e apaga a sessão.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema incluindo o código seguinte em todas as páginas (que não a de login) e na de login, respetivamente...

Páginas normais:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

  // Verifica se não há a variável da sessão que identifica o usuário
  if ($_SESSION['nivelAcesso'] != 1) {

      $_SESSION['destino'] = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
      // Redireciona o visitante de volta pro login
      header("Location: /"); 
      exit;
  }
```

Página do login:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['destino']) && $_SESSION['destino'] != "") {
                                header("Location: ".$_SESSION['destino']);

                            }else{
                                if($_SESSION["nivelAcesso"] == "1"){
                                header("Location: geral");

                            }elseif($_SESSION["nivelAcesso"] == "2"){
                                header("Location: artesaos");

                            }else{
                                header("Location: voluntarios");

                            }
                            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Colocando em prática a Idéia do Marciano, tendo em vista seu comentário. Sugiro que faça assim:

```
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start(); // Verifica se não há a variável da sessão que identifica o usuário
if ($_SESSION['nivelAcesso'] != 1) {

// Redireciona o visitante de volta pro login
    $_SESSION['destino'] = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
require_once "config.php";
   // Verificar se está logado, se não reencaminha para a página de login
?>
```